# With Android BLE, do I need to request a large MTU when reading byte data back, or only when writing?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I understand that in Android, the MTU for writing data to a Characterisitc is around 23 bytes (3 bytes used so you have around 20 bytes free) and that you can request a higher MTU (up to 512) to allow you to write/send larger data packets to a bluetooth device.

However, do you also need to do this when *reading* data from a characterisitic?

Both Reading and Notification updates?

If say, I have a characteristic that sends data in 123 byte chunks, but I only ever have to send at most 2 bytes to it, do I need to negotiate a large MTU?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can recommend you to read the ATT and GATT chapters in the Bluetooth Core standard. Those explain the protocol.

By default Android does not negotiate a larger MTU than the default (23 bytes). You can do that yourself though by calling the `requestMtu` function.

Android automatically under the hood uses "Write Long Characteristic Values" and "Read Long Characteristic Values" when the MTU is not big enough when reading/writing values in order to transfer the whole value. However these procedures are very inefficient since they require multiple roundtrips. The read operation also is not atomic.

Notifications and Indications don't have any "Long" variant with multiple roundtrips, so these will be truncated to fit the MTU.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll try and dig up those chapters at some point.

I understand the requestMtu call can request a larger MTU (might not work but should return the current MTU) - however the Android documentation heavily implies this is only needed to Write to a characteristic.

I can't tell if I need to do it just for reading. Android docs are never the best.

In my current testing, I'm *not* requesting a larger MTU and I have a characteristic sending me data (read) in byte[124] chunks and it all seems fine, but I don't know if thats just the phones I test on.

Comment: Would the implication be that 'maybe' the phone will handle it but I should request at least 127 MTU (124 + header) bytes even just for reading?

Comment: The Android BLE docs are quite useless as it doesn't say anything useful at all nearly. I think my answer already covers your follow-up questions. Basically you should increase your MTU if you want better performance and if you have notifications that are big.